# Notice: Undefined index updateAddress

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm building rest api to update customer address and I get the following error

```
{
"message": "Notice: Undefined index: UpdateAddress in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\yourParts\\lib\\internal\\Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\MethodsMap.php on line 75",
"trace": "#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\yourParts\\lib\\internal\\Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\MethodsMap.php(75): Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', 'C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', 75, Array)\n#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\lib\\internal\\Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceOutputProcessor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\Reflection\\MethodsMap->getMethodReturnType('vendor_name\\\\Customer\\\\...', 'UpdateAddress')\n#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\app\\code\\Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest.php(308): Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\ServiceOutputProcessor->process(true, 'vendor_name\\\\Customer\\\\...', 'UpdateAddress')\n#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\app\\code\\Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest.php(216): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\var\\generation\\Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor.php(37): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\lib\\internal\\Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http.php(135): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\lib\\internal\\Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#8 {main}"}
```

that's my webapi.xml route

```
<route url="/V1/customers/updateAddress/:firstName/:lastName/:company/:phoneNo/:fax/:stAddress/:city/:zipCode/:country/:addressId" method="PUT">
    <service class="Bit68\Customer\Api\Customer\CustomerApiInterface" method="UpdateAddress"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>

</route>
```

that's my class

```
<?php

namespace vendor_name\Customer\Model\Customer;

use \vendor_name\Customer\Api\Customer\CustomerApiInterface;
use \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface;

class CustomerApi implements \Bit68\Customer\Api\Customer\CustomerApiInterface{

/**
* @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
*/
private $customerRepository;

/**
* @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
*/
private $accountManagement;

/**
* @var \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface
*/
private $userContext;

/**
* @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository
*/
private $addressRepository;


/**
* @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
* @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
* @param \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface $userContext
* @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository $addressRepository
*/
public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
\Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
\Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface $userContext,
\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository $addressRepository){
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
    $this->userContext = $userContext;
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;

}




 /**
 * @api
* @param string $firstName
* @param string $lastName
* @param string $company
* @param string $phoneNo
* @param string $fax
* @param string $stAddress
* @param string $city
* @param string $zipCode
* @param string $country
* @param int $addressId
* @return bool
*/
public function updateAddress($firstName,
$lastName,
$company = null,
$phoneNo,
$fax = null,
$stAddress,
$city,
$zipCode,
$country,
$addressId){

    $data = [
        "firstName" => $firstName,
        "lastName" => $lastName,
        "company" => $company,
        "phoneNo" => $phoneNo,
        "fax" => $fax,
        "stAddress" => $stAddress,
        "city" => $city,
        "zipCode" => $zipCode,
        "country" => $country,
        "addressId" => $addressId
    ];

    $address = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);

    if(!empty($data) && $address){
        $address->setFirstname($firstName);
        $address->setLastname($lastName);
        $address->setCompany($company);
        $address->setTelephone($phoneNo);
        $address->setFax($fax);
        $address->setStreet(["Almaza"]);
        $address->setCity($city);
        $address->setCountryId($country); //sme issues about countryId
        $address->setPostcode($zipCode);

        $this->addressRepository->save($address);

        return true;

    }

    return false;
}


/**
*
* @api
* @return array
*/
public function getAddressId(){
    $customerId = $this->userContext->getUserId();
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    $customerAddresses = array();
    if($customer && $this->isLoggedIn()){
        $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
        foreach($addresses as $address){
            array_push($customerAddresses, (array)$address);
        }

    }

    return $customerAddresses;
}

/**
* @return bool
*/
public function isLoggedIn(){
    $customerId = $this->userContext->getUserId();
    $userType = $this->userContext->getUserType();
    if($userType == UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}




?>
```

that's my interface

```
<?php

namespace vendor_name\Customer\Api\Customer;

interface CustomerApiInterface{


/**
* @api
* @return array
*/
public function getCustomerData();

/**
* @api
* @param string $firstName
* @param string $lastName
* @param string $company
* @param string $phoneNo
* @param string $fax
* @param string $stAddress
* @param string $city
* @param string $zipCode
* @param string $country
* @param int $addressId
* @return bool
*/
public function updateAddress($firstName,
$lastName,
$company = null,
$phoneNo,
$fax = null,
$stAddress,
$city,
$zipCode,
$country,
$addressId);

/**
* 
* @api
* @return array
*/
public function getAddressId();


}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `di.xml` it should look like this

> app/code/Bit68/Customer/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Bit68\Customer\Api\Customer\CustomerApiInterface" type="Bit68\Customer\Model\Customer\CustomerApi"/>
</config>
```

Comment: I've already written that in di.xml

Comment: @YomnaMansour Please share `CustomerApiInterface.php` in question

Comment: I've updated the question